# Update. How to access values returned by native SQL NHibernate query?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I have this table (table name is price):

```
value productId ShopID      Timestamp
1.30    1          5        2015-05-30 05:20:28.000
1.20    1          5        2015-05-29 16:09:34.000
1.00    1          5        2015-05-29 16:09:43.000
1.20    1          5        2015-05-29 16:09:50.000
1.20    1          5        2015-05-29 16:09:58.000
1.00    2          5        2015-05-29 16:10:13.000
1.00    2          5        2015-05-29 16:10:17.000
1.00    1          6        2015-05-29 16:10:42.000
1.00    1          5        2015-05-30 15:02:44.000
1.30    1          5        2015-05-30 15:03:24.000
```

I want to get value that has been entered the most times in the latest date for each shop for single product. Note that the I want to convert timestamp to date.

Right now I have this SQL query:

```
select count(*), value, Productid, shopid
from price 
where shopid = 5 
    and productId = 1 
    and cast(floor(cast(Timestamp as float)) as datetime) 
        in (select max(cast(floor(cast(Timestamp as float)) as datetime)) as [date] from price)
group by value, Productid, shopid
order by count(*) desc
```

It returns ordered count for single product and single shop like this:

```
Count   value   Productid   shopid
2       1.30        1          5
1       1.00        1          5
```

In ideal case I would like to get only the row with biggest count, but I guess this would be ok as well.

Up to this point I've been using QueryOver queries in my solution, but I guess anything that can be used in c# would be ok.

TIA

**Update**

Following suggestions in comments I am trying to use native SQL. I've got this code to get distinct shop ids, and this is working fine.

```
var shopIds =
                _session.CreateSQLQuery("select distinct shopid from price where productid = " + productId).List();
```

Then I am trying to execute main query for each shop, after which I would like to find a single instance of most frequent price like this:

```
List<Price> query;

            foreach (var shopId in shopIds)
            {


                 var querySubResult = _session.CreateSQLQuery("select value, productId, shopId" +
                                                        "from price " +
                                                        "where shopid = " + shopId +
                                                        "and productId = " + productId +
                                                        "and cast(floor(cast(Timestamp as float)) as datetime) " +
                                                        "in (select max(cast(floor(cast(Timestamp as float)) as datetime)) as [date] from price)" +
                                                        "group by value, Productid, shopid" +
                                                        "order by count(*) desc")
                                                        .AddScalar("value", NHibernateUtil.Decimal)
                                                        .AddScalar("productId", NHibernateUtil.Int64)
                                                        .AddScalar("shopId", NHibernateUtil.Int64).List();

            query.Add(_session.QueryOver<Price>()
                .Where(x => x.Value == querySubResult[1].value)
                .And(x => x.Product.ProductId == querySubResult[1].productId)
                .And(x => x.Shop.ShopId == querySubResult[1].shopId));
            }
```

As I understand AddScallar defines output properties for returned data from sql statement, but I can't access none of the variables in the list.

What is wrong? Should it be aproached in diferent way? Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: There are other ways for C# to send queries to SQL Server without using Hibernate, for instance, using SqlConnection.

Comment: I am already using NHibernate in my solution and I would like to stick to that, since it is already configured and working, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Unless it needs to be database agnostic you could parameterize the existing query and use CreateSQLQuery.

Comment: @user3677314 . . . If you have native SQL queries running, I would suggest using a native interface, unless you have a good design reason for using Hibernate.  The conversion sounds troublesome, and there is an easy work-around.

Comment: Thank you both. I am trying to use native SQL, but have run into some problems. Please see updated post for them, maybe you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in [NHibernate Reference, Scalar Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html#d0e11290):

> This will return an IList of Object arrays (object[]) with scalar
>   values for each column in the (CATS) table.

Example:

```
var result = _session.CreateSQLQuery("...")
                     .AddScalar(...).AddScalar(...)
                     .List();

var row0property0 = ((object[])result[0])[0];
var row0property1 = ((object[])result[0])[1];
```

I think you could also do `...List<object[]>` to avoid having to cast to `object[]` when accessing property values.

The greatest use of raw SQL queries in NHibernate is when you tell NHibernate to actually build entity instances from the returned data.

Comment: I get red squiggly line under "[0]" in querySubResult[1][0] if I convert querySubResult[1].value to  querySubResult[1][0]. Why could that be?

Comment: I don't know - what does Visual Studio/the compiler tell you is wrong?

Comment: Visual studio shows.

cannot convert from 'NHibernate.IQueryOver<WebApiPrice.Data.Entities.Price,WebApiPrice.Data.Entities.Price>' to 'WebApiPrice.Data.Entities.Price'

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @user3677314 I've updated my answer to include the casting that should be required when using the non-generic version of `List()`. As for the "cannot convert" error, it looks like you are trying to add a QueryOver instance to a list of Price instances.